# ASP.NET MVC 2 DropDownList not rendering

Tags: asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

so I don't understand what I am doing wrong here. I want to populate a DropDownList inside the master page of my ASP.NET MVC 2 app.

Projects.Master

```
<div id="supaDiv" class="mainNav">
 <% Html.DropDownList("navigationList"); %>
</div>
```

MasterController.cs

```
namespace ProjectsPageMVC.Controllers.Abstracts
{
    public abstract class MasterController : Controller
    {
        public MasterController()
        {
          List<SelectListItem> naviList = new List<SelectListItem>();

          naviList.Add(new SelectListItem
          {
           Selected = true,
           Text = "AdvanceWeb",
           Value = "http://4168web/advanceweb/"
          });

          naviList.Add(new SelectListItem
          {
           Selected = false,
           Text = " :: AdvanceWeb Admin",
           Value = "http://4168web/advanceweb/admin/admindefault.aspx"
          });

          ViewData["navigationList"] = naviList;
        }
    }
}
```

The DropDownList is not even showing up in the DOM and I am at a loss as to what I am doing wrong.

ProjectsController

```
namespace ProjectsPageMVC.Controllers
{
    public class ProjectsController : MasterController
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change

```
<% Html.DropDownList("navigationList"); %>
```

to

```
 <%=Html.DropDownList("navigationList") %>
```

Comment: The equals sign is the difference, though I think you also have to use the overload that includes the SelectList

Comment: As long as the data is of type SelectList, you don't need to un-box it, see Dave's answer. Personally I prefer strongly typed data over magic strings.

Comment: @Gabe This has bitten me countless times.

Comment: The equals sign indicates a literal value, the semicolon indicates a method call.

Answer (score 2):

Change your markup:

```
<%= Html.DropDownList("navigationList", (SelectList)ViewData["navigationList"]); %>
```

Comment: this throws an error: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem]' to type 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectList'.

Comment: Your value in the ViewData should be an IEnumerable<SelectListItem>